# Asynchronous Save/Return of list in repository

Tags: c#, asynchronous, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern

I am working on a WebAPI in .NET Core, for accessing DB I have a synchronous repository pattern implementation. Now I am changing the approach from synchronous to asynchronous and I have encountered a couple of issues that I don't understand.

I have this function:

```
public List<object> Save(List<T> entities)
    {
        return entities.Select(x => _session.Save(x)).ToList();
    }
```

How to make it asynchronous?

Second function:

```
 public async Task<List<Comment>> GetCommentsForPost(long postId)
    {
        try
        {
            return await (List<Comment>)_session.QueryOver<Comment>()
            .Where(x => x.PostId.Id == postId && !x.Deleted)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Created).Desc
            .ListAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e.Message + e.InnerException + e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }          
    }
```

Those two functions are not related. I put them so I can show where I have problems. 
As you can see I am trying to make it work in the second function. All the issues I am facing are generating same error: "... does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter() and no accessible extension method GetAwaiter() accepting..."

Can someone please show me how this should be done correctly?

**EDIT:**
This is what I have found that works:

```
var t = entities.Select(async x => await _session.SaveAsync(x)).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(t);
        return t;
```

However I am not sure if this is a good approach?

Comment: unrelated, but don't do this: `logger.Error(e.Message + e.InnerException + e.StackTrace);` do this: `logger.Error(e.ToString());`

Comment: Okay thank you for that, it is unrelated but guess its helpful :) so great and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Function 1:

```
public async Task<List<object>> Save(List<T> entities)
{
    return await entities.Select(x => _session.Save(x)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Function 2: just remove `.Result;`.

Comment: Also, never use `.Result`. Ever. If it *must* be synchronous, at least use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: I am not sure if this should be as comment, but: Function1: "IEnumerable<object> does not contain definition for ToListAsync(); and Function2: cannot convert from system...threading..task to list